# How to get Excel cell Value in VBA with single quote if in the starting of text

Tags: excel, vba

How to get Excel cell Value in VBA with single quote if in the starting of text.

For Eg.
Cell A1 has Value '123. I get value 123 only in VBA. I need '123.

Comment: Are you sure that the value is the 4-element string `"'123"` rather than the 3-element string `"123"` which has been entered as `'123` at the user interface (where a leading single quote causes Excel to interpret the rest of what you type as a string)? In any event, a [mcve] would help.

Comment: (Actual question: How to get raw cell value from VBA?)

Comment: What's your current code?

Comment: If in A2 you enter the formula `=LEN(A1)` do you get 3 or 4? I suspect that you will get 3 rather than 4. Perhaps the real question is how to enter the value `'123` into a cell. One answer is to type `''123` (with 2 single quote marks, the first causing Excel to interpret the rest, including the second quote mark, as text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423862/4996248) shows, you can use `.PrefixCharacter` to get the initial single quote mark (if any), which then be concatenated with the value of the cell:

```
Range("A1").PrefixCharacter & Range("A1").Value
```